# Selenium WebDriver - No driver is working for me

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to get Selenium tests running. I'm using C#. I'm having a problem with every driver I tried.

### Chrome

```
var options = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\Vilem\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\";

using (IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(options))
{
...
```

Seems like chromedriver.exe was found but it could find the Chrome binary. I set up the path to chrome.exe explicitly after automatic search failed. I even tried it with "chrome.exe" at the end. I always get the same result:

**Could not find Chrome binary at:**

**C:\Users\Vilem\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application**

### Firefox

```
new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
```

I also tried it with a profile set:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"E:\...\FirefoxProfile"); 
new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
```

Error I'm getting:

**Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms**

### IE

```
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IEDriver\", ieOptions);
```

The folder with the driver is also set in PATH.

The error I'm getting:

```
No response from server for url http://localhost:6955/session
```

Is there something I'm missing? I would be happy if any of them got working.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you keep the drivers in the same directory as the test assembly? So that you do not need to tell Selenium where to look, since it's first port of call is to look in the same directory as the assembly, so is there any difference if you keep the driver in the same folder?

Comment: I tried that as well, no change unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I got Chrome and IE working by putting the .exe for ChromeDriver and IE_driver in the project /bin/ folder

Ex.

```
VisualStudio2010/Projects/ProjName/ProjName/bin/chromedriver.exe
```

Then when setting up my tests I did:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
...
private IWebDriver chrome;
...
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
    {
        chrome= new ChromeDriver();
        baseURL = "url-goes-here";
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }
...
```

You can download the .exe from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

### Chrome

> Could not find Chrome binary at: 
>   C:\Users\Vilem\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application

I think you have to specify the whole path including the executable. Like
`C:\Users\Vilem\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` (just guessing, have currently no access to a Windows machine)

### Firefox

> Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms

You should not get that permanently. Quickest solution to tell you without asking a lot of questions back: Restart (or logout-login). If you still get that after reboot, have a look at questions about it and maybe post your own.

Comment: I did try the path including "chrome.exe" as well with the same result. I'll try Firefox again tomorrow after I boot up my work PC and let you know.

Comment: No change in using the Firefox driver after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the path including .exe. So, your code would be as follows:

```
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\Vilem\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IEDriver\iexplore.exe", ieOptions);
```