# Selenium WebDriver - Firefox - Unable to bind to locking port within 45000 ms

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to get Selenium tests running with Firefox. I'm using C#.

```
new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
```

I also tried it with a profile set:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"E:\...\FirefoxProfile"); 
new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
```

Error I'm getting:

**Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms**

I even tried uninstalling Firefox including profiles and re-installing again. Didn't help.

---

FYI: I have a question concerning 3 selenium webdrivers. I'm trying to split the question into multiple so the discussion is easier. Original: 
[Selenium WebDriver - No driver is working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456416/selenium-webdriver-no-driver-is-working-for-me)

Comment: What version of selenium are you using

Comment: i had a similar problem and it was resolved with a simple reboot. Presumably some environment variable needed to be set properly after install.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips on debugging this:

I found the quickest way to test if the problem exists, is by browsing to

```
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
```

and then trying to create a firefox session there.

I had the issue with FF 18.0 and Selenium server 2.28.0 (the latest releases at the time of writing). I made sure Windows Firewall wasn't blocking the Selenium server and then rebooted the machine - which did the trick. So I assume Ross Larson is right.